# Inline style for border being ignored on <table> in Outlook

Tags: html, css, html-email, outlook-2016

Essentially have this `<table style="border: 1px solid #000000">` which should put a small border around the entire table. Looks fine in every other email client except Outlook 2016. It has every border that is at the `<td>` level, but not the outside border at the `<table>` tag.

`border-top: 1px solid #000000` also has the same issue.

The HTML `<table border="1">` attribute won't work for my case because it is way too thick.

Furthermore, here is every attribute in that table tag in case that could be causing the issue:

```
<table
  class="module"
  role="module"
  data-type="code"
  border="0"
  cellpadding="0"
  cellspacing="0"
  width="100%"
  style="table-layout: fixed;border: 1px solid #000000;"
>
```

I ended up just doing `<table style="border-collapse: collapse">` and `<td style="border: 1px solid #0000000">`, which worked fine, but just curious about what I originally had.

Comment: I was unable to find any "definite" answer for this. From what it seems, there is still a huge majority of email clients dating all the way up to 2017 that just don't handle borders very well. It sounds like if you want borders to appear, there are just a bunch of weird workarounds you have to do. Sorry I couldn't get you a clear answer, it's one of those things that everyone implements differently due to their not being a spec saying how it should be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
 <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding="0" border="1" bordercolor="red">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Lorem Ipsum dummy text~
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

This was working fine for me. try using both, on style and outlook code as well. Hope it'll work